# How to store HTML as a value of an object property in react state?

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I have this state in my FAQ component:

```
this.state = {
            faqs: [
                {
                    question: "Some question string",
                    answer: "Some answer string"
                },
                {
                    question: "Some question string",
                    answer: "Some answer string"
                }
            ]
        };
```

Which I loop over to in the render method to display each FAQ set. However, my 'answer' property needs to contain `<p></p>` tags as in:

```
{
   question: "Some question string",
   answer: "<p>Some answer string</p> <p>Some answer string</p>"
}
```

How do I achieve this in react?

Comment: Why id "some answer string" listed twice in your render?

Comment: The correct way of doing this in React is to create a small SFC component that takes a single prop `answer` and returns HTML wrapped in `p` tag. Then in the `render` method of the component, loop over the `faqs` array and call this `Answer` component passing the `answer` from the object.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I am just giving an example text. The actual text is different.

Comment: No that was not my question - you clearly have "<p>Some answer string</p> <p>Some answer string</p>" - why have you repeated the answers from 2 different faq entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, this may be a case for react's builtin `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.

The `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop provides a mechanism for specifying the html contents of an element by means of a string value, rather than via JSX.

To illustrate this concept, see the following code:

```
// I am assuming that your render function looks something like this:
function render() {

  const faqs = this.state.faqs

  return (<div>
    faqs.map(faq => {    
      return (<div>
          <h3> {{ faq.question }}</h3>
          {/* make use of dangerouslySetInnerHTML in this way to 
              account for HTML tags/markup in the answer variable */}
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ _html : faq.answer }}></div>
        </div>)    
    })
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? The name sounds like it's dangerous to use? @DacreDenny

Comment: Yes, it means users of your app are vulnerable to XSS attacks , so is best avoided if possible

Answer (score 5):

Simply wrap it with Fragments.

```
{
    question: "Some question string",
    answer: <><p>Some answer string</p> <p>Some answer string</p></>
}
```

or with this

```
{
    question: "Some question string",
    answer: <React.Fragment><p>Some answer string</p> <p>Some answer string</p></React.Fragment>
}
```